# Is it possible to match first level of non-direct descendants?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like a particular CSS rule to apply **only** to the first level of `section` descendant elements inside the `.body` element, no matter how deeply nested they are.

For example if given a hierarchy resembling this:
`.body -> div -> section.a -> div -> section.b` then I would want my styling to apply only to `section.a`.

The same goes for
`.body -> section.a -> div -> section.b`
`.body -> footer-> div -> section.a -> div -> section.b`
etc.

Is it possible to do this in CSS, without setting a class on the elements?
So far I was not able to find any indication that it's possible.

Comment: No, that is not possible, as you would need a parent selector, which does not exist, and make this question a dupe of such.

Comment: Well, you can actually do like this, doesn't look nice but does the job: https://jsfiddle.net/0cc6qyu0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use child selector:

```
.body > div > section
```

Comment: That does not work when we have a variable number of nested elements between .body and section.

Answer (score 0):

There is no css selector that supports what you want, but you can achieve the same with this:

Suppose that all of your sections have a default red color, then you want just the first level of non-direct section elements to be blue

```
.body section {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Ups, but that is going to make all section descendants to be blue.
To fix that, you revert that operation on every first-section section descendant:

```
.body section section {
  // make every one else (that's not the first descendant) red again.
  background-color: red;
}
```

Hope that's not too cumbersome in your case.

Comment: Thank you! That's not perfect but close enough!